# Как работает Гугл переводчик?

Tags: алгоритм, поиск

Вроде бы никаких запросов на сервер он не отправляет... разве такое возможно локально?

Comment: Отправляет, отправляет. Попробуйте загрузить гуглопереводчик, выдернуть шнур интернета и перевести что-нибудь.

Comment: Несколько лет назад вообще весь софт работал только локально, так что да, это возможно))

Answer (score 2):

Отправляет запросы, это видно даже невооруженным взглядом по меняющейся строке запроса:

```
https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru#ru/en/%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82
```

Где фраза зашифрована с помощью [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)